# where to put bitmap.recycle() to reduce out of memory issues

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

I am using the following method to reduce the sizes of bitmaps to 200dp X 200dp from any original size.  This is supposed to prevent crashing due to out of memory issues that would happen if I did not reduce the size of the bitmaps.   However even after using BitmapFactory.opitons to reduce the size of bitmaps I am still getting out of memory issues.

Someone suggested that I use bitmap.recycle(); I have never used this before and I am a bit confused because of where the location logcat is telling me the out of memory is happening.

logcat tells me the memory problem is happening in the image reduction method on the return statement of the method that returns a bitmap here:

```
  return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, options);
```

so where would I call bitmap.recycle() in this code?

here is code for the entire method:

```
   public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String fileName, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

       // logCat says running out of memory here on the return statement
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, options);


}
```

Comment: if you are using API level greater than 10 then just use this option in your manifest at application level. `android:largeHeap="true"`

Comment: try matching image size to screen size. get screen DPI and adjust image based on that.